# Replacing/flipping any specfic binary bit of a column using python

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I want to flip any specific bit of a dataframe that also doesn't affect the neighbour bits.
For example, my dataframe look like this,

```
s = pd.Series(["01100", "10010", "11100", "10011"])
0    01100
1    10010
2    11100
3    10011
```

Now, I want it as (after flipping only the 3rd bit),

```
0    01000
1    10110
2    11000
3    10111
```

I know how to flip last position bit using panda string slice but not any specific position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it use regex

```
#partitioned the string, so you can point out the bit you want to flip
# check the value of the bit, and accordingly flip with if-else
s.str.replace(r'(..)(.)(.*)',
              lambda x: x.group(1)+ 
              ('0' if x.group(2)=='1' else '1')
              +x.group(3), regex=True )
```

```
0    01000
1    10110
2    11000
3    10111
dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry for late respose. The way you showed it, work perfectly. But I am working with larger data, will try to fit it with that too.. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to vote from my account, could be because of new acc.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are a more natural representation than `str` for this
binary bit-flipping exercise.

You call it "the 3rd bit", but conventionally we name it the 2nd,
reserving the zeroth bit for the low-order units position.
We wish to flip the `k`th bit with `^` XOR.

```hs
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
fmt = partial(str.format, '{0:08b}')

k = 2
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(n=s.apply(int, base=2)))
df['binary'] = df.n.apply(fmt)
df['flipped'] = (df.n ^ 2 ** k).apply(fmt)
>>> df
    n    binary   flipped
0  12  00001100  00000100
1  18  00010010  00011010
2  28  00011100  00010100
3  19  00010011  00011011
```

Comment: thanks  for showing an alternate way.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) methods:

```
s = s.str.slice(stop=2) + (1-s.str.get(2).astype(int)).astype(str) + s.str.slice(start=3)
```

print(s):

```
0    01000
1    10110
2    11000
3    10111
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, I was looking for similar kind of str.slice operation.